# Express alternative recurring times in iCalendar

Tags: icalendar, rrule, rfc5545

Is there a way to express the following in iCalendar? (possibly using RRULEs?)

> Between 9am and 5pm every day except Sundays when it is between 10am and 4pm.

Can I create multiple RRULEs? Which ones have precedence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iCalendar does not have a notion of events with a hole in the middle of the duration. So even without talking about recurring event, you can not create with a single event something like from 9AM to 10AM and from 4PM to 5 PM

As a consequence, you need to actually create 3 events:

```
DTSTART:2013xxxxT090000
DURATION:PT1H
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY

DTSTART:2013xxxxT100000
DURATION:PT6H
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA

DTSTART:2013xxxxT160000
DURATION:PT1H
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY
```

As far as having multiple RRULE, this was supported in RFC2445 but it has been deprecated in RFC5545 (just like EXRULE) due to lack of support and complexity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is a shame that multiple RRULEs were deprecated. It makes a whole genre of complex events impossible to define. E.g. Supermarket shopping hours + different shopping hours on public holidays.